Gnome extensions like System Monitor in Alpine linux can't see gliptop
System Monitor or Tophat gnome extensions don't work in fresh installation of Alpine linux. I can see error:

Requiring GTop, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GTop' (any
version) not found

I have installed these two:
apk add libgtop gcompat

so I think that library is in the OS, however gnome shell extension can't see it.
Any idea how to proceed with debug, how can I see what's wrong?

When checking tophat readme https://github.com/fflewddur/tophat it says that on deb based linux libgtop is usually installed, however gir1.2-gtop-2.0 need to be installed in order to make bindings for the gtop system monitoring library. Which I'm not able to find or undestand what it does and how to replicate that in alpine :-(

chatgpt said that I need to build libgtop library manually using ./configure --enable-introspection=yes parameter and that should create file /usr/share/gir-1.0/Gtop-2.0.gir

however that seem to be hard thing to do
